# Get user meta data from woocommerce_created_customer hook in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am using woocommerce API to create a customer API is working fine and the new customer is creating fine into WP. But the issue is when I am using a hook "woocommerce_created_customer" I am not able to get user meta data like "first name", "last name" etc

Here is a part of my code:

````
```
$this->loader->add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', $plugin_admin, 'add_user_to_zendesk', 50 );
public function add_user_to_zendesk( $user_id ) {
        if ( isset( $user_id ) && ! empty( $user_id ) ) {
            $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id )->data;
            error_log('USER DATA'. print_r( $user, true ) );
            error_log('USER METADATA'. print_r( get_user_meta($user_id), true ) );
         }
}
```
````

Here is a response in log file

```

````
[01-Sep-2018 08:30:50 UTC] USER DATAstdClass Object
(
    [ID] => 99
    [user_login] => geek2
    [user_pass] => XXXXXXXXX.
    [user_nicename] => geek2
    [user_email] => geek2@gmail.com
    [user_url] => 
    [user_registered] => 2018-09-01 08:30:49
    [user_activation_key] => 
    [user_status] => 0
    [display_name] => geek2
)

[01-Sep-2018 08:30:50 UTC] USER METADATAArray
(
    [nickname] => Array
        (
            [0] => geek2
        )

    [first_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [last_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [description] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [rich_editing] => Array
        (
            [0] => true
        )

    [syntax_highlighting] => Array
        (
            [0] => true
        )

    [comment_shortcuts] => Array
        (
            [0] => false
        )

    [admin_color] => Array
        (
            [0] => fresh
        )

    [use_ssl] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )

    [show_admin_bar_front] => Array
        (
            [0] => true
        )

    [locale] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [wp_capabilities] => Array
        (
            [0] => a:1:{s:8:"customer";b:1;}
        )

    [wp_user_level] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )

    [_yoast_wpseo_profile_updated] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1535790649
        )

)
```
````

Can someone please help to figure out the issue...

Comment: Have you checked in `wp_usermeta` database table for the created user ID… maybe there is no user meta data created or no meta values for the meta keys`first_name` and `last_name`. What are you using for user creation?

Comment: Yes after some time I checked usermeta by below code 
get_user_meta( 96, 'first_name',true ); and it returning a firstname.

Comment: I think there is some delay in meta insert, and the hook is calling before.
Is there any solution to overcome this issue?

Comment: You could try to use `woocommerce_new_customer` action hook that has $customer_id as unique function argument…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

First you could try one of this 2 alternatives *(to add in your code)*:

1) The Wordpress way using `WP_User` Class:

```
// Get an instance of the WP_User Object
$user = new WP_User( $user_id );

// Get the first name and the last name from WP_User Object 
$first_name = $user->first_name;
$last_name  = $user->last_name;
```

2) The Woocommerce way using `WC_Customer` Class and methods:

```
// Get an instance of the WC_Customer Object
$customer = new WC_Customer( $customer_id );

// Get the first name and the last name from WC_Customer Object 
$first_name = $customer->get_first_name();
$last_name  = $customer->get_last_name();
```

---

Then looking at the [`WC_Customer_Data_Store`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Customer_Data_Store.html) source code there is an interesting action hook that could be used: [`woocommerce_new_customer`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Customer_Data_Store.html#124) that has a unique argument, the `$customer_id`.

> In the source code `$customer->get_first_name()` and `$customer->get_last_name()` appear in the code, so they exist and you can get them from the `WC_Customer` instance Object using the `$customer_id`, as described here below…

---

**Last possibility**

As the user meta data seems to be delayed and Woocommerce seems to be using WordPress functions, you could try to use the WordPress hook [`add_user_meta`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.8/src/wp-includes/meta.php#L96) which has 3 arguments:

- `$user_id`
- `$meta_key`
- `$meta_value`

But I don't know how to include it in your code, hoping that you could get the data from `WP_User` Object or `WC_Customer` Object.

Comment: Thanks Man, the second solution is working fine for me.