# Access first name of user in WooCommerce account acitivation mail (DOI via WooCommerce Germanized)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We have a custom registration page for our WooCommerce site which is based on a Business Bloomer shortcode and added an input field for the first name of the user. The code within our functions.php looks like this:

```
/**
 * @snippet       WooCommerce User Registration Shortcode
 * @author        Rodolfo Melogli
 * @compatible    WooCommerce 3.6.5
 * @donate $9     https://businessbloomer.com/bloomer-armada/
 */

// THIS WILL CREATE A NEW SHORTCODE: [wc_reg_form_bbloomer]
add_shortcode('wc_reg_form_bbloomer', 'bbloomer_separate_registration_form');

function bbloomer_separate_registration_form()
{
    if (is_admin()) return;
    if (is_user_logged_in()) return;
    ob_start();

    // NOTE: THE FOLLOWING <FORM></FORM> IS COPIED FROM woocommerce\templates\myaccount\form-login.php
    // IF WOOCOMMERCE RELEASES AN UPDATE TO THAT TEMPLATE, YOU MUST CHANGE THIS ACCORDINGLY

?>

      <form method="post" class="woocommerce-form woocommerce-form-register register" <?php do_action('woocommerce_register_form_tag'); ?> >

            <?php do_action('woocommerce_register_form_start'); ?>

            <?php if ('no' === get_option('woocommerce_registration_generate_username')): ?>

                <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                    <label for="reg_username"><?php esc_html_e('Username', 'woocommerce'); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="reg_username" autocomplete="username" value="<?php echo (!empty($_POST['username'])) ? esc_attr(wp_unslash($_POST['username'])) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine
         ?>
                </p>

            <?php
    endif; ?>

            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="reg_email"><?php esc_html_e('Email address', 'woocommerce'); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="email" id="reg_email" autocomplete="email" value="<?php echo (!empty($_POST['email'])) ? esc_attr(wp_unslash($_POST['email'])) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine
     ?>
            </p>

            <?php if ('no' === get_option('woocommerce_registration_generate_password')): ?>

                <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                    <label for="reg_password"><?php esc_html_e('Password', 'woocommerce'); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="password" id="reg_password" autocomplete="new-password" />
                </p>

            <?php
    else: ?>

                <p><?php esc_html_e('A password will be sent to your email address.', 'woocommerce'); ?></p>

            <?php
    endif; ?>

            <?php do_action('woocommerce_register_form'); ?>

            <p class="woocommerce-FormRow form-row">
                <?php wp_nonce_field('woocommerce-register', 'woocommerce-register-nonce'); ?>
                <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button woocommerce-button button woocommerce-form-register__submit" name="register" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Register', 'woocommerce'); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Register', 'woocommerce'); ?></button>
            </p>

            <?php do_action('woocommerce_register_form_end'); ?>

        </form>

   <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}

/**
 * @snippet       Add First to Register Form - WooCommerce
 * @sourcecode    https://businessbloomer.com/?p=21974
 * @author        Rodolfo Melogli
 * @credits       Claudio SM Web
 * @compatible    WC 3.5.2
 * @donate $9     https://businessbloomer.com/bloomer-armada/
 */

///////////////////////////////
// 1. ADD FIELDS

add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start', 'bbloomer_add_name_woo_account_registration' );

function bbloomer_add_name_woo_account_registration() {
    ?>

    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
    <label for="reg_billing_first_name"><?php _e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_first_name" id="reg_billing_first_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ); ?>" />
    </p>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <?php
}

///////////////////////////////
// 2. VALIDATE FIELDS

add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_errors', 'bbloomer_validate_name_fields', 10, 3 );

function bbloomer_validate_name_fields( $errors, $username, $email ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'billing_first_name_error', __( '<strong>Achtung</strong>: Vorname ist ein Pflichtfeld!', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
    return $errors;
}

///////////////////////////////
// 3. SAVE FIELDS

add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'bbloomer_save_name_fields' );

function bbloomer_save_name_fields( $customer_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_first_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) );
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'first_name', sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_first_name']) );
    }

}
```

Since our site is based in Germany we use the WooCommerce Germanized plugin with the DOI (double opt-in) functionality. So a user receives an activation mail which they have to click in order to active the account. Within the activation mail we want to have a more personal feeling, thus include the first name of the user. There we added the original email template from WooCommerce Germanized to our child theme.

**The problem is that the only value I can access (is displayed in the actually delivered email) is $user_login** which returns the automatically created username. How can I access the first name of the user which is saved as first name and billing first name. The template within our child theme looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Customer new account activation email.
 *
 * @see https://github.com/vendidero/woocommerce-germanized/wiki/Overriding-Germanized-Templates
 * @package Germanized/Templates
 * @version 1.6.4
 */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

    <p><?php printf( __( 'Hi %s,', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $user_login ) ); ?></p>

    <p><?php printf( __( "Thanks for creating an account on %s. Please follow the activation link to activate your account:", 'woocommerce-germanized' ), esc_html( $blogname ) ); ?></p>

    <p><a class="wc-button button"
          href="<?php echo esc_url( $user_activation_url ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Activate your account', 'woocommerce-germanized' ); ?></a>
    </p>

<?php if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) == 'yes' && $password_generated ) : ?>

    <p><?php printf( __( "Your password has been automatically generated: <strong>%s</strong>", 'woocommerce-germanized' ), esc_html( $user_pass ) ); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>

    <p style="font-size:75%;"><?php printf( __( "If you haven't created an account on %s please ignore this email.", "woocommerce-germanized" ), esc_html( $blogname ) ); ?></p>

    <p style="font-size:75%;"><?php printf( __( 'If you cannot follow the link above please copy this url and paste it to your browser bar: %s', 'woocommerce-germanized' ), esc_url( $user_activation_url ) ); ?></p>

<?php
/**
 * Show user-defined additional content - this is set in each email's settings.
 */
if ( $additional_content ) {
    echo wp_kses_post( wpautop( wptexturize( $additional_content ) ) );
}
?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email ); ?>
```

I already tried to populate the first name as described here (https://wordpress.org/support/topic/new-account-email-insert-first-name/) and to access it via $user->display_name but this did not work.

I also tried the solution provided here ([Get user meta data from woocommerce_created_customer hook in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52126496/get-user-meta-data-from-woocommerce-created-customer-hook-in-woocommerce)) to access first name via Customer object. The code would then look like below. I didn't work either.

```
<p><?php $customer = new WC_Customer( $customer_id ); printf( __( 'Hi %s,', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $customer->get_first_name() ) ); ?></p>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need to find the user. I assume you don't have access to the user ID, if you do you can skip the first line, and insert the user_id at the appropriate point.

Then you need to get the first name [from the meta data](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta). According to your code you store it in the metadata field `'billing_first_name'`. And then it's a matter of inserting it in your email.

```
<?php 

$the_user = get_user_by('login', $user_login);
$first_name = get_user_meta($the_user->ID, 'billing_first_name', true);

?>
<p><?php printf( __( 'Hi %s,', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $first_name ) ); ?></p>
```

Comment: I had to use `'first_name'` instead of `'billing_first_name'` when used in the "New account" template, triggered during checkout.
But thanks for the right direction still.

Answer (score 3):

Actually WooCommerce has that template on default, which includes username, email, myaccount url and much more, I dont think there will be difference between woc eng or grmn, except language.

```
defined('ABSPATH') || exit;

do_action('woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email); ?>

//To get user_name on registration you need to call get_user_by('id',$user_login); OR get_user_by('login',$user_login); OR get_user_by('user_name',$user_login);

$user = get_user_by('id',$user_login);
$first_name = get_user_meta($user,'first_name',true);

//and call like this

<p><?php printf(esc_html__('Hi %s,', 'woocommerce'), esc_html($first_name)); ?></p>
//translators: %s: Customer username 
<p><?php printf(esc_html__('Hi %s,', 'woocommerce'), esc_html( $user_login)); ?>
//translators: %1$s: Site title, %2$s: Username, %3$s: My account link

<p><?php printf(esc_html__('Thanks for creating an account on %1$s. Your username is %2$s. You can access your account area to view orders, change your password, and more at: %3$s', 'woocommerce'), esc_html($blogname), '<strong>' . esc_html( $user_login) . '</strong>', make_clickable(esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink('myaccount')))); 
?></p>

// phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped 

<?php if ('yes' === get_option('woocommerce_registration_generate_password') && $password_generated) : ?>

//translators: %s: Auto generated password

    <p><?php printf(esc_html__('Your password has been automatically generated: %s', 'woocommerce'), '<strong>' . esc_html($user_pass) .'</strong>'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php
//Show user-defined additional content - this is set in each email's settings 

if ($additional_content) {
    echo wp_kses_post(wpautop( wptexturize( $additional_content)));
}

do_action('woocommerce_email_footer', $email);
?>
```

Here is the template https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/emails/customer-new-account.php

Comment: If I use `<p><?php printf( __( 'Hi %s,', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $first_name ) ); ?></p>` it does not display anything after „Hi“ in the mail

Comment: would you please change this `$first_name = get_user_meta($user,'first_name',true);` to this `$first_name = get_user_meta($user,'billing_first_name',true);` your call is billing_first_name

Comment: It works with the suggested solution by Tschallacka so I guess it will also work with your suggested change. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

get the user information by login

`$customer = get_user_by('login', $user_login);`

and get the name using the user id

`$firstName = get_user_meta($customer->ID,'billing_first_name',true);`

if the user is not registered, so, you can use this

`esc_html( $firstName ) );`

instead to

`esc_html( $customer->get_first_name() ) );`